# JSF Renderer - Store encoded output in string for relocation

Tags: jsf, components, renderer

I would like to store the response generated by the encodeAll() method of a UIComponent into a string to use the content somewhere else.

I alread tried to set up a FacesContextWrapper which provides a special ResponseWriter that should write the content to a StringWriter, but it does not work. It seems my ResponseWriter is never called.

I know there is the other way and encode in the right place and probably I will do so, but I would still like to know how to do that. Especially the compression of the content, there should be no spaces between tags and no linebreaks, is very important.

EDIT:

I have some facets and the content of these is used to be passed to javascript, because of that i would need the rendered content of the facets to be compressed to a single line.
First i tried to wrap around the writer to get the content, then compress it myself and append it to the javascript as parameter, but it didn't work.
Now i render the content at the right place, but it's not compressed to a single line.

EDIT2:

Javascript Strings can only be multilined if "\n\" is used at the end of the line. I can't change the content produced by the encodeAll() method so it's really hard. I really will have to capture the content that is generated and then manually compress the string! But how to do that? ResponseWriter-wrapping did not work for me.

SOLUTION:

I would like to share my solution with others!
ResponseWriter offers a method called `cloneWithWriter(Writer w)` which i didn't know. By using this method with a custom StringWriter implementation you can capture the output in a buffer and finally use that buffer as string

Comment: Mojarra 2.1.1 on glassfish 3.1.1

Comment: So, the concrete functional requirement is to trim all unnecessary whitespace from the entire response? But then I don't understand the requirement to use the content somewhere else.

Comment: Is there any other way of making the data available to the JS, rather than needing it to be on one line? Can you give an example of the facet output and how the JS should be consuming it?

Comment: The facet can have any tags as content such as simple text, outputTexts, panelGroups etc. When I pass the generated content in apostrophes and the content has line breaks, it will cause an error.